# What does arr.sort(key=lambda x: x:(x[0],int(x[1]),int(x[2])) 's lambda function write in def function?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, tuples

Here is a question which I understand the lambda function work ,but can't
rewrite to def function.

example:

```
lst= [(2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)] 
lst.sort(key= lambda x:(x[0]))
```

like

```
def takeSecond(elem):
return elem[1]
lst= [(2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]
lst.sort(key=takeSecond)
```

but How is the below lambda to rewrite in def function  ?

```
lst.sort(key= lambda x:(x[0],int(x[1]),int(x[2])))
```

Thanks to instructor.

Comment: `def takeFirstThreeAndConvertToInt(x): return (x[0],int(x[1]),int(x[2]))`

Comment: Didn't use any loop to write it?

Comment: @TonyLin: Why do you think you need a loop? The processing for each element isn't consistent (two are converted to `int`, one left untouched) so even if there were enough elements being processed to justify the loop, it would be awkward to force it into a loop structure; since the number of elements is so few, there's no benefit at all.

Comment: Thanks for explaining ,I sudden know it just about the key of order,doesn't need loop to judge.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference involved here is that `lambda`s return their expression implicitly. So just use the same code, with explicit return:

```
def key_on_three(x):
    return x[0], int(x[1]), int(x[2])

lst.sort(key=key_on_three)
```

Because of the lack of ambiguity, it's safe to omit the parentheses around the three values being returned here, but you could just as easily write `return (x[0], int(x[1]), int(x[2]))` if you preferred (they're exactly equivalent).